# Running a variable that is stored as string in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, simulink

Here is the deal, I have lots of variables that are stored in Excel. Those are the values that my Simulink model uses. What I want to do is to extract the descriptions of all of 'em automatically.

What I have done so far is the following,

I read them from column and defined a txt array to hold them as strings.
Created another string as s2 to combine ".Description" string with variable names.
I combined them and generated another array called descriptioner.
Read the length from the txt array for counter.
Used a small while loop to add .Description to all of them.

Where I am stuck is that I cannot run them and get the descriptions.

I used eval() but it fails. Is there a way to call those strings as variables to get the descriptions?

```
clc
filename = 'variables.xlsx';
[num, txt] = xlsread('variables','A:A')
L=length(txt)
s2='.Description'
i=1;
while i<=L
    descriptioner(i) = strcat(txt(i),s2)
    i=i+1;
end
```

Comment: Can you show how you used eval() and had it fail?  Royi is right, so there may be something else going on.  Perhaps you can add an edit with your `eval()` command and the argument you passed.

Comment: It was failing when I used () instead of {} but couldn't automate it by using the following
descriptions(i)=eval(descriptioner{i})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try allocating your `descriptioner` variable as a cell before doing your loop.  Here's one way to try:

```
clc
filename = 'variables.xlsx';
[num, txt] = xlsread('variables','A:A');
descriptionsCell = cell(size(txt));
for i=1:numel(txt);
   descriptionsCell{i} = [txt{i},'.Description'];    
   fprintf(1,'The description of %s is %s\n',txt{i},eval(descriptionsCell{i}));
end
```

Let me know if this works or not.  It works on my machine for a simulated example, but I'm always learning new things.

Comment: Excellent.  Glad to hear it; thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I also have a small problem while trying to assign them to an array. The {} does not fit with the (). Any idea to overcome this? Like the following,

output(i)=eval(descriptionsCell{i}) or "output=" or "output{}".

Comment: The issue with assigning text strings to arrays is that the text strings are often of different lengths, while an array requires each row to be the same length.  That is, for an NxM character array, each of the N rows is M characters long.  I'm guessing your descriptions are not all the same length.  Feel free to ask another question with the error you are running into and post the link to that question as a comment here.  Myself or someone else can see it and follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute MATLAB command which is given in String one should use [`eval()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).

Comment: If I read the question right, Deniz tried that and it failed.